# Error en migracion de proyecto REACT-FIREBASE JS a TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, firebase

Me tira este error pero la verdad ya no encuentro como resolverlo.[image: error]

Dejo link de codigo
[proyecto](https://vscode.dev/github/MatiasDBrites/Proyecto-React-Vite-PL)

Espero que algun heroe sin capa nos pueda echar la mano, desde ya muchas gracias.

Comment: Por favor no uses imagenes y utiliza texto por favor. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando usas Typescript necesitas especificar el tipo de objeto que estas usando en tu caso me parece que podrias crear un tipo o una interface para el objeto user:

```
interface IUser {
    displayName: string;
    email: string;
    emailVerified: boolean;
    isAnonymous: boolean;
    phoneNumber: string;
    photoURL: string;
    providerData: never[];
    providerId: string;
    uid: string;
}
```

Sin embargo si pudieras mostrar todo el detalle del error seria buenisimo ya que en VS Code Web EsLint y Lint estan deshabilitados por lo que el error no se ve:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Muchas gracias Edson ya lo solucionamos, efectivamente ese era el problema. Lo resolvimos agregando 2
[arreglodeerror1.png](https://postimg.cc/3dYQ3NjC)